# Find the coordinates of hanging segment bound by strings

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

So we have a segment [AB] that is hanged by two strings on the left and on the right. We know the distance between the two strings pivots (D) and the length of the two strings (L - left and R - right). We also now the segment length (M) and the angle it makes to the strings support (z). We consider the left string pivot the origin. (x -> right, y -> down).

How can I find the coordinates of A and B?

I got to:
$$Ax=cos(alfa)*L;Ay=sin(alfa)*L$$
$$Bx=D-cos(beta)*R;By=sin(beta)*R$$
$$Bx=Ax+cos(z)*M;By=Ay-sin(z)*M$$
so this results in:
$$D-cos(beta)*R=cos(alfa)*L+cos(z)*M$$
$$sin(beta)*R=sin(alfa)*L-sin(z)*M$$
with the 2 unknowns **alfa** and **beta**. Where can I get an extra equation?

Thanks!

Comment: Think of this as a physics problem.

Comment: @Moti It's actually a physics problem. I'm trying to determine the reverse transform from this (http://dlacko.org/blog/2017/06/04/v-plotter-math-coordinate-transformation-rotation-compensation/). So on that site it shows how to transform x,y (cartesian) to left/right (polar). For the calibration procedure I need to be able to do the reverse and this is where I'm stuck (determining the coordinates).

Comment: Set the forces at the ends of the segment in the direction of the strings - equilibrium achieved for all forces and moments.

Comment: @Moti yes, but I'm stuck at calculating alfa/beta or the coordinates of points. :)

Comment: You need the force equations - where are they? The weight of M has an impact?